# How to get the header authorization key in python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, http-headers, bearer-token

I want to access the data of a website using requests, but it requires an "authorization" header to get the response. I can get it manually by logging in, but there's no point in making a program if it's like this. ***Also, it resets every few minutes***. How can I provide my log-in credentials and get the authorization key?

I tried this:

```
import requests

headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"}

login_url = 'https://example.com/login'

login_data = {
    'username': 'username',
    'password': 'password'
}

session = requests.session()
login_response = session.post(login_url, data=login_data, headers=headers)

print(login_response.status_code) # always gives 404
```

and also this:

```
import requests

headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"}
username = "username",
password = "pass",
url = "https://url.com/login"
with requests.session() as session:
    reponse = session.post(url, auth=(username, password), headers=headers)

print(reponse) # it gives 404 also
```

How can I do that?

EDIT: I used this code and got 200, but I didn't get the authorization key. How can I get it?

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"}
username = "user",
password = "pass",
url = "https://url.com"
response = requests.get(url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, password), headers=headers)

print(response) # 200
print(response.headers) #doesnt have "authorization"
```

Comment: Are you certain your response should contain this on `headers`? [Authorization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) is a request header not response (usually). Is it possible you should receive Authorization key in the cookies and not in headers?

Comment: Yes, you're right, I can see it in the cookies in chrome dev tools, but when I print response.cookies, I get an empty list. How can I retrieve the auth key?

Comment: Can you check by `print(response.cookies['authorization_key'])`? Put cookie name for authorization key in `authorization_key`'s place

Comment: I switched from 'requests' to 'selenium' and now I'm getting the token using driver.get_cookies()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. I switched from '`requests`' to '`selenium`' and now I'm getting the token using '`driver.get_cookies()`'